# Configure virtual directory in sftp server

Tags: xubuntu, directory, vsftpd

I've recently shifted from Windows to Xubuntu. I'm trying to implement an sftp server for my home. In Windows, I used Bitvise. WHen searching for sftp servers for linux, I came accross vsftpd. So, I installed it. But, I'm unable to setup virtual directories (i.e. directories that refer to different physical folders). Does this application support virtual directories? If yes, how to set them up? If not, can anyone please refer me another server that does?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else answered, and I managed to solve it, I'm posting the answer myself.
Well, it was pretty straightforward. Instead of configuring it inside an sftp server, I did it the general way. I created a new directory under `/var/www` (or anywhere else). Then, I used the `bind` command to mount the desired directories there.

`#As an example
sudo mount --bind /some/where /else/where
 #mounts /some/where under /else/where`

Then, I just selected that directory as the home of the user. Done.